# Start Activity with a variable

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I do the name of the activity variable with a string?

```
 Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                         xxx.class);
```

If my string is "a" it will be:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                             a.class);
```

else, if my string is "b":

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                             b.class);
```

how can I concatenate this? Thank you so much

Comment: `if (myString.equals("a")) in = new Intent(this, a.class); else in = new Intent(this, b.class);`

Comment: No, this is a example but I have more than 20 activities, I need something more automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot check it right now but this should work:

```
Intent I = new Intent(this, Class.forName("your.package.ClassName"));
```

However this is a little dangerous IMHO.  This would allow to start any activities from outside of your app. This would e.g. allow to open some internal activities from outside which are not exported.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I concatenate this?

Ideally, you don't. You use something else, like a `switch` statement or a `HashMap<String,Class>` lookup or something.

That being said, you are welcome to [use `Class.forName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) if you really want.

Comment: And how can I use Class.forName, some example please? :)